# Check list of dictionaries against set of conditions and return matching key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to do a 'skimming' or reduction method in dictionaries in which it will returns me a set of results from a given set of condition.

However my current method is more of an additive where it will simply lists me any items that fulfills any one of the condition.

```py
# Only list me items that are 'menuA/a100 + menuB/b100', or 'menuA/a100 + menuB/b200'
# However, there are times where I could have more than 1 menu(s) `menuX`
# condition = {'menuA':['a100']} should return only 'wrong2'
conditions = {'menuA':['a100'], 'menuB':['b100', 'b200']}

my_items = [
    {'correct' : {'menuA': ['a100'], 'menuB': ['b200']}},
    {'wrong1' : {'menuA': ['a200'], 'menuB': ['b200']}},
    {'wrong2' : {'menuA': ['a100']}},
    {'wrong3' : {'menuB': ['b100']}}
]


result = []

for m in my_items:
    for mk, mv in m.items():
        for c in conditions:
            if c in mv.keys():
                if [i for i in condition[c] if i in mv[c]]:
                    result.append(mk)

# I used `set` as it returns me `correct` twice... Even so, it is returning me every items.
print(set(result)) # set(['correct', 'wrong1', 'wrong2', 'wrong3'])

# Expecting the result to be returning me `correct`
```

Comment: what is `checked`?

Comment: @LanteDellarovere it should be `condition`... Have updated my post. sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to follow your logic:

```
result = []
for item in my_items:
    k, v = list(item.items())[0]
    if all(any(x in v.get(kc, []) for x in vc) for kc, vc in conditions.items()):
        result.append(k)

>>> print(set(result))
{'correct'}
```

**Update:**

if you want items with more `menu` than `conditions` to be discarded, here a simple fix:

```
for item in my_items:
    k, v = list(item.items())[0]
    has_same_keys = set(v) == set(conditions)
    at_least_one_value = all(
        any(x in v.get(kc, [])for x in vc) 
        for kc, vc in conditions.items())
    if has_same_keys and at_least_one_value:
        result.append(k)
```

Comment: If the `conditions` has become `{'menuA':['a100']}`, it is now returning `set(['wrong2', 'correct'])` as the result, where I am expecting `wrong2` to be the only returned output since there is 1 item that fulfills the condition...